# How to make GlobalKey list with list.generate method?

Tags: flutter

I want to make 12 widgets and know the coordinates of each of them.
And I found that GlobalKey must be assigned to get coordinates.
For that, I make a List to make GlobalKeys and assign them, but I got Stack overflow error.

I have no idea what I do wrong.
Anyone to help?

```
List<GlobalKey> keyCap =
List<GlobalKey>.generate(12, (int index) => keyCap[index] = GlobalKey());

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      key: keyCap[0],
      color: Colors.red,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem but can't understand why it works.. anyway, :

```
List<GlobalKey> keyCap = List<GlobalKey>.generate(12, (index) => GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'key_$index'),growable: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
List<GlobalKey> keyCap = [];

List<int>.generate(12, (int index) { keyCap.add(GlobalKey());});
```

Comment: I'm so sorry but it didn't work with that error. (A value of type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>>'. )

Comment: my bad, please check again

Comment: It didn't work too but thanks for the help. When I put second line, all of 'List' types shows error = "Functions must have an explicit list of parameters.  Try adding a parameter list."